# Выборка элементов на чистом JS

Tags: javascript

Для того, чтобы задать стили для всех элементов с классом `.box` на jQuery, достаточно написать следующее:

```
$('.box').css('background', 'red');
```

Как реализовать тоже самое на чистом JS?
Вот моя не вполне удачная попытка:

```js
function $(selector) {
  var prefix = selector[0];
  var selector = selector.substring(1);

  switch (prefix) {
    case '#':
      return document.getElementById(selector);
    case '.':
      var elem = document.getElementsByClassName(selector);
      for (var i = 0; i < elem.length; i++) {
        return elem[i];
      };

    default:
      return document.getElementsByTagName(prefix + selector);
  }
}



$('.box').style.background = 'red';
```

```html
<div>
  <p class="box">hello</p>
  <p>world</p>
  <p class="box">000</p>
  <p>111</p>
</div>
```

Стили применились только к первому элементу с классом `.box`, хотя я возвращаю эти элементы из цикла ...

JS в процессе изучения, поэтому прошу сильно меня не "ругать"))

Comment: делая `return` вы **покидаете** функцию, в данном случае функцию `$`

Comment: Посмотрите тут: http://javascript.ru/unsorted/top-10-functions#8-getelementsbyclass

Comment: Стоит поступить по аналогии с jQuery и хранить список выбранных элементов внутри, предоставляя к ним доступ с помощью функций

Comment: return elem[i]; Возвращает только первый элемент.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Слишком разные результаты возвращает данная функция:

отдельный элемент, либо коллекция элементов.

Из-за этого нужно либо следить за тем, чтобы с результатом обращались в зависимости от типа, либо скрыть его внутри, выставив наружу нужные функции для работы с выбранными элементами.

Кроме этого проблема в данном коде заключается в том, что обычным `return` нельзя **приостановить** выполнение цикла, и потом продолжить его, при использовании `return` происходит полный возврат из функции, поэтому все остальные элементы теряются.

Если уж брать за основу jQuery, то стоит посмотреть как сделано в нем.

список элементов хранится внутри, и по большому счету доступ к нему осуществляется посредством функций.

Простейшую версию можно реализовать так:

```js
(function(window) {

  var my = function(selector) {
    return new my.fn.init(selector);
  }

  my.prototype = my.fn = {
    version: '0.0.1',
    constructor: my
  };
  //выбираем элементы
  var init = my.fn.init = function(selector) {
    this.context = Array.from(document.querySelectorAll(selector)); //всегда имеем массив элементов
  }
  init.prototype = my.fn;
  my.fn.css = function(cssProperty, cssValue) { // добавляем метод для работы с css
    this.context.forEach(function(el) {
      el.style[cssProperty] = cssValue
    });
    return this;
  }

  return window.my = my;
}(window));

my('.box').css('background', 'red');
```

```html
<div>
  <p class="box">hello</p>
  <p>world</p>
  <p class="box">000</p>
  <p>111</p>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2):

Например, вот так:

```js
var box = document.querySelectorAll('.box');
for (var i = 0; i < box.length; i++) {
    box[i].style.background = 'red';
}
```

```html
<div>
  <p class="box">hello</p>
  <p>world</p>
  <p class="box">000</p>
  <p>111</p>
</div>
```

Comment: Cпасибо. Но это очевидное решение, к тому-же не рациональное, т.к. захламляет основной код. Задача вынести это в функцию $().
Пока изучаю информацию из комментария @andy.37 ... Надеюсь, что найду ответ там.

Comment: @Astor В чём суть захламления-то? Ну сделайте `var $ = document.querySelectorAll`, если так нравится.

Comment: @Astor, это, кстати, довольно рациональное решение, как минимум разбор селектора передан нативной части

Comment: @Discord, подозреваю что не нравится открытый цикл в коде

Comment: @Discord, суть захламления в цикле. Если в документе есть только класс .box, то все гуд, а если есть и другие классы? - тогда будет дублирование кода. Кроме того, вопрос был: "выборка элементов на чистом JS".
Допускаю, что я не прав))

Comment: @Astor, а где вы нашли в примере "нечистый" JS?

Comment: @Grundy, нигде)), я просто скопировал вопрос из заголовка. Имелась ввиду выборка элементов. Да, в данном ответе выборка осуществлена, но хочется более элегантного решения с использованием функции $(), чтобы выборка происходила в ней.

Comment: @Discord, _var $ = document.querySelectorAll_ так просто не получится :-) нужно биндить на документ хотя бы

Comment: @Grundy Тьфу, жабоскрипт. `var $ = q => document.querySelectorAll(q)` прокатит? Ну а магия, что работа с коллекциями как с элементами — это фенечка jQuery, тащить её в нормальный код не надо. Есть `foreach` в конце концов. Ах, ну да, это же жабоскрипт. Ещё послайсить функцией массива на почти массиве надо будет.

Comment: @Discord, там `Array.from` уже есть вместо слайса :-)

Comment: @Grundy О. Пошёл спамить на большой СО. Ещё б найти, где я этот слайс почерпнул, чтобы другие не пошли по стопам предков...